# How to get standardised date/time from abbreviated non-English format in PHP?

Tags: php, date, php-carbon

I have an input date string of something like `Sett21`, which is in Italian, and I need to get a standardized format such as 01/09/2021.

Is there a way to create a date from an abbreviated non-English string? I'm attempting to use Carbon and it can handle a date string abbreviated in English fine:

`$date = Carbon::create("Sept2021");`

Output: `Wednesday, September 1, 2021 12:00 AM`

However it fails the Italian abbreviated month `Sett`.

Comment: Not sure if localization covers _parsing_ dates as well, or only formatting them for output - but that is the first thing I would try. https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-localization If not, "translating" the Italian month name in your input string to the English one using str_replace with arrays would be an easy workaround.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution via an array with the Italian month names as in CBroe's comment.

```
$input = 'Sett21';

$list = 'genn,febbr,mar,apr,magg,giugno,luglio,ag,sett,ott,nov,dic';
foreach(explode(',',$list) as $key => $month){
  $in = preg_replace('~'.$month.'~iu',($key+1)." ",$input);
  if($in !== $input) break;
}

$date = Carbon::createFromFormat('!m y',$in);
echo $date;
//or
$dateTime = DateTime::createFromFormat('!m y',$in);
echo "\n";
echo $dateTime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Output:

```
2021-09-01 00:00:00
2021-09-01 00:00:00
```